# Changing default font weight for FiraSans and smath

Tags: fonts

I'd like to use `FiraSans` as default for my documents. The default values work fine, but I'd like **FiraSans Medium** as my default bold font and **FiraSans Light** as my default regular font.

I already tried `\renewcommand{\seriesdefault}{l}` and 
`\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{mb}` but it has no effect (this worked while I used OpenSans - but with FiraSans only the regular font is affected, but the bold font stays untouched).

The several font series can be looked up here: ftp://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/fonts/fira/latex/FiraSans.sty

Further, I have a problem with `sfmath` as it uses FiraSans Regular even when I use `\renewcommand{\seriesdefault}{l}` for FiraSans Light. I'd like to have the math font in light weight, too. Is that possible?

MWE:

```
% ATTRIBUTES
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\parskip\baselineskip
\parindent0pt

% FONT
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}
\usepackage{sfmath}

% MATH
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{How it is now (default)}

\textbf{This is bold} and this is regular font weight with $\sin(123456789)$ math.

\subsubsection{Hot I'd like it}

{\firalight But I'd like Fira Light as my standard regular font.}

{\firamedium And Fira Medium as my standard bold font.}

{\firalight And \texttt{sfmath} shall adapt Fira Light for $\sin(123456789)$ math, because at the moment it uses Fira Regular for math.}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: Have you tried `\usepackage[light,sfdefault]{FiraSans}`?

Answer (score 5):

Something like this? `FiraSans` has a rather non-standard font setup, and `sfmath` hard-codes the font series. You may need to fish out and redo some more declarations but this should give you the idea:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sfdefault,light]{FiraSans}
\usepackage{sfmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\makeatletter
\def\bfseries@sf{m}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{normal}{\math@encoding}{\math@sfdefault}{l}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}{\math@encoding}{\math@sfdefault}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{SFMath}{\math@encoding}{\math@sfdefault}{l}{sl}
\SetSymbolFont{SFMath}{normal}{\math@encoding}{\math@sfdefault}{l}{sl}
\SetSymbolFont{SFMath}{bold}{\math@encoding}{\math@sfdefault}{m}{\mathnormal@bold@shape}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\subsubsection{How it is now (default)}

\textbf{This is bold} and this is regular font weight with $\sin(123456789)$ math.

\end{document}
```

[image: Fira Sans]

Note that it is debatable whether you should typeset a document entirely in sans or maths in it at all.