# Bold in FiraSans not working

Tags: fonts, bold

I am trying to make part the text bold when using the FiraSans font. A solution that used to work for me was this one: [Changing default font weight for FiraSans and smath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268291/changing-default-font-weight-for-firasans-and-smath)

After reinstalling MikTex (and also the Fira package), however, the solution no longer works. And exits with the code: "Undefined controle sequence \bfseries".

The code still works with one of my friends. After comparing all installed packages, we were able to reduce it the following minimal example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sfdefault, light]{FiraSans}
\makeatletter
\def\bfseries@sf{m}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
{\bfseries text}
%{text}
\end{document}
```

Does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

You have just forgotten to switch to sans serif:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sfdefault, light]{FiraSans}
\makeatletter
\def\bfseries@sf{m}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\textsf{\bfseries text}
text
\end{document}
```